# Add rows in csv when second csv has the same first row

Tags: python, csv

I'm learning Python so sorry for stupid questions..

I have two files:

**list.csv**

```
john
mary
joanna
lucas
kate
```

**db.csv**

```
john^chief^portland
mary^secretary^ny
joanna^supervisor^washington
```

What I want to achieve is to compare both files and as an output have
alphabeticaly sorted by first column abd where the name is not in db add `None` in second column like this:

**output.csv**

```
joanna^supervisor^washington
john^chief^portland
kate^None
lucas^None
Mary^secretary^ny
```

I'm beginning to fight with it starting from this code which I found on SO:

```
masterlist = list(reader22)

for hosts_row in reader21:
    row = 1
    found = False
    for master_row in masterlist:
        results_row = hosts_row
        if hosts_row[0] == master_row[0]:
            results_row.append('FOUNDTHISLINE in master list (row '
                               + str(row) + ')')
            found = True
            break
        row = row + 1
    if not found:
        results_row.append('THISLINENOTFOUND in master list')
    writer23.writerow(results_row)
```

Please help to understand how should it be done best way.

Comment: Which value goes to third column then ?

Comment: When you say "same first row", do you mean _column_?

Comment: Yes sorry column. MMF: no third column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy and efficient to do what you want using only the `csv` module and Python's own built-in data structures, such as lists and dictionaries:

```
import csv

with open('list.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    masterlist = sorted(row[0] for row in csv.reader(csvfile))

with open('db.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    db = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='^')}

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='^')
    for name in masterlist:
        writer.writerow([name] + db[name] if name in db else [name, 'None', ''])
```

Contents of the `output.csv` created:

```
joanna^supervisor^washington
john^chief^portland
kate^None^
lucas^None^
mary^secretary^ny
```

Comment: guys correct me if im wrong but in python < 2.7 this line: `db = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='^')}` should look like this? `db = dict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='^')) `

Comment: Lucas: I don't know in what version of Python [Dictionary displays](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays) were introduced, but it's been there for a long time. That said, the [alternative](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) method you show to create the `dict` from a  [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) producing a sequence of `key`, `value` pairs should also work in versions from 2.4 up to and including 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect case for the Pandas library.  I know you're just learning, but check it out for data manipulation (please ignore the numbering :) )

```
In [37]: list_df = pd.read_csv('list.csv', header=None)

In [38]: db_df = pd.read_csv('db.csv', sep='^', header=None)

In [51]: db_df
Out[51]:
        0           1           2
0    john       chief    portland
1    mary   secretary          ny
2  joanna  supervisor  washington


In [48]: list_df
Out[48]:
        0
0    john
1    mary
2  joanna
3   lucas
4    kate

In [52]: df = list_df.merge(db_df, how='left')

In [53]: df
Out[53]:
        0           1           2
0    john       chief    portland
1    mary   secretary          ny
2  joanna  supervisor  washington
3   lucas         NaN         NaN
4    kate         NaN         NaN

In [54]: df.sort(0)
Out[54]:
        0           1           2
2  joanna  supervisor  washington
0    john       chief    portland
4    kate         NaN         NaN
3   lucas         NaN         NaN
1    mary   secretary          ny
```

From there you can just call the df.to_csv function and get the output you're looking for.

(To write back)
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: How do you write back to the file?

Comment: Answer edited to point to the docs.  Its pretty straight forward.